# How to populate checkbox text value based on radio button selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and have been stuck on one part of it for awhile. I cant seem to find an answer (probably because I'm not searching for the correct things). Anyways, I have an MVC project that connects to a MySQL db on the back end. I want this page to flow as the user selects more options. I have 2 tables at the moment, one for environment and the other for database. When the user selects the env, a query runs in the background based on env_id to populate the available databases. I have followed a few videos which led me to where I am now. I can get the Environment box to populate fine, but cannot figure out how to pass the value between div's. If I move the foreach up into the first div, I can get it to populate one value, but nothing on click.

If someone could point me to a good tutorial that does something similar, that would be awesome.

**controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using apollo.Models;
using System.Data;

namespace apollo.Controllers
{
   public class dbController : Controller
   {      
       // GET: db    
       DBAccessLayer.db dblayer = new DBAccessLayer.db();

       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           DataSet ds = dblayer.get_environment();
           ViewBag.environment = ds.Tables[0];
           return View(ds);

       }

       public void get_database(int env_id)
       {
           DataSet ds = dblayer.get_database(env_id);
           List<database> databaselist = new List<database>();
           foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
           {
               databaselist.Add(new database{                      
                   db_name = dr["db_name"].ToString()
               });
           }
           Session["database"] = databaselist;            
       }


   }
}
```

**view**

```
@{

}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
</script> 

<h2>QueryTool</h2>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h3>Environment</h3>
                @{
                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.environment.Rows)
                    {
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id=" @dr["env_id"]" value=" @dr["env_id"]" checked>
                                @dr["env_name"]

                                @{
                                    ((apollo.Controllers.dbController)this.ViewContext.Controller).get_database((Convert.ToInt32(dr["env_id"])));
                                }                                


                            </label>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h3>Database</h3>
                @{
                    foreach (apollo.Models.database dbname in Session["database"] as List<apollo.Models.database>)
                    {
                        @dbname.db_name
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**db access layer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace apollo.DBAccessLayer
{
    public class db
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString);

        public DataSet get_environment()
        {
            string query = "Select * from env";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }

        public DataSet get_database(int env_id)
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select * from permission where env_id = @env_id", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("env_id", env_id);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quite grasped the concept of MVC.  Views shouldn't be calling the controller, instead the controller supplies data to the view via the model.

Maybe the [MS MVC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) will help

Answer (score 0):

Few recommendations:

1. Please use dependency injection in your controller. See this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection  and this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/eec362/dependency-injection-in-mvc/
2. For data access layer, you should start with Repository design pattern.
3. View should receive model instead of calling controller method.
4. Avoid using session instead you should use model. this model will be passed from controller method to view.
5. Neither controller nor view should handle any logic. That is model's responsibility.

Comment: #5 is incorrect - logic should be in the controller

Comment: @AUSteve if you will include business logic in controller then what services will do? Controller and its action method handles incoming browser requests, retrieves necessary model data and returns appropriate responses.

Comment: The question was only talking about the "MVC" pattern, not another multi-layer application architecture.  There is no mention of "service" in the question or your answer.  Given the OP is "new to MVC" it would be more useful to restrict advice to those specifics to ease the learning curve